# Extract the pointer from a V_${i}_T variable name in a bash loop

Tags: bash, raspbian, gammu

Suppose I have several variable names like

```
V_1_T = a
V_2_T = b
V_3_T = c
...
```

and I want to extract the pointers a, b , c, ... in a bash loop in order to concatenate the values. My explicit wish is about reconstructing a message separated in several parts as explained in the [gammu-smsd documentation](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/run.html#passing-message-text-to-program).
I've tried the example in the doc but it doesn't work. The reason is that the code never points to the pointer of the variables but to the variables themselves, i.e. I get `V_1_T` at best and never `a` as I would.

I've also tried to put

```
${V_${i}_T} ; ""$"V_${i}_T"
```

with and without escape symbols for the commas, ..., but nothing worked ...

Any ideas ?

I'm working on the latest version of Raspbian + RaspberryPi.

Answer (score 2):

Use indirect parameter expansion:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  t="V_${i}_t"
  echo "${!t}"
done
```

This avoids the use of `eval` shown in the docs you linked to.

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot. But i guess it was not a problem with `eval` am I correct ? Rather it has to do with my ignorance in bash isn't it ?

Comment: @FraSchelle, ...for discussion of why `eval` use is undesirable, see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)